# Install the module TIA "manually"

Tags: python, module, pip

I'm trying to install the module [TIA - Toolkit for integration and analysis](https://github.com/bpsmith/tia). I used the command

> pip install tia

on several computers and it worked fine, however when I'm in a private network behind a proxy/firewall, the code does not work (I can't connect).
Is there any other way to replicate the code without using an internet connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the package by copying the `tia` folder from the github project you linked to your `Libs/site-packages/` folder, so that you have the folder `Libs/site-packages/tia`.

Usually this works for all pip modules, except when they have special setup code.

Notice that this project depends on numpy and pandas, so you will also have to install those two manually. I think at least on windows there are installers available though.